# Using arrays in methods?

Tags: arrays, methods

I've been trying to learn java and programming in general for APCS.  But I've got a question regarding access of an existing array in a method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Gravity
{
    static final double G = 6.67 * Math.pow(10, -17);
    public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
    {
        int arrayLength = masses.length;
        for (int i = 0; (i < arrayLength); i++)
        {
            double value = (G * mass[i])/Math.pow(radius[i], 2.0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
        double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
        double[] masses = {3.3022 * Math.pow(10,23), 4.8685 * Math.pow(10,24), 5.9736 * Math.pow(10,24), 6.4185 * Math.pow(10,23), 1.8986 * Math.pow(10,27), 5.6846 * Math.pow(10,26), 8.6810 * Math.pow(10,25), 1.0243 * Math.pow(10,26), 1.312 * Math.pow(10,22)};
    }
}
```

And it doesn't seem to be working as intended, I'm getting an error at int arrayLength = masses.length.  Is there something special I have to to get a method to recognize a variable located elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
int arrayLength = masses.length;
```

Should be

```
int arrayLength = mass.length;
```

Your method takes in a `mass` arg not a `masses`.

If you're using an IDE, you can hover of the problem and it will tell you what the problem is.

**Edit: Other problems**

Your method has a return type of `double[]` but you don't return anything in the method

Answer (score 0):

Methods can't access local variables in other methods.  Since your `calcGravity` array takes arguments, if you call `calcGravity` from `main` you can pass the arrays in using those arguments:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
    double[] masses = {3.3022 * Math.pow(10,23), 4.8685 * Math.pow(10,24), 5.9736 * Math.pow(10,24), 6.4185 * Math.pow(10,23), 1.8986 * Math.pow(10,27), 5.6846 * Math.pow(10,26), 8.6810 * Math.pow(10,25), 1.0243 * Math.pow(10,26), 1.312 * Math.pow(10,22)};

    double[] gravities = calcGravity(radii, masses);
}
```

Alternatively, you could define `names`, `radii`, and `masses` as static variables in the `Gravity` class, which makes them visible to all methods in the class:

```
public class Gravity
{
    private static String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    private static double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
    private static double[] masses = {3.3022 * Math.pow(10,23), 4.8685 * Math.pow(10,24), 5.9736 * Math.pow(10,24), 6.4185 * Math.pow(10,23), 1.8986 * Math.pow(10,27), 5.6846 * Math.pow(10,26), 8.6810 * Math.pow(10,25), 1.0243 * Math.pow(10,26), 1.312 * Math.pow(10,22)};

    // ...
}
```

Then you can refer to `radii` and `masses` from within `calcGravity`, but this'll mean that `calcGravity` is hard-coded to always calculate the gravity of *those* planets.  it's better to pass the radius and mass information into `calcGravity` as arguments, because that way it can work for *any* planets.

---

On a separate note, it'd be a good idea to write a `calcGravity` method that takes just *one* mass and radius (not arrays) and returns just *one* result.  Then the array-based version can call the non-array version in a loop.  It's good to keep those things separate since looping an array has nothing to do with calculating gravity.